# ESP32: Add micro sd card reader on 2nd SPI bus

Tags: arduino, esp32, sd-card, spi, rfid

I am trying to create a music box for my son, but i am having some trouble getting the SD card to work.

The idea is that when we scan a RFID tag we should get the corresponding mp3 file from the SD card.

I am using:

- a ESP32 DOIT DEVKIT V1
- RFID reader is a RFID-RC522
- Micro SD card reader has no brand or model number on it. It just says "Micro sd card adapter" on the back and has 6 pins: cs, sck, mosi, miso, vcc, gnd

My problem is that both the RFID reader and the Micro SD Card reader should use SPI.

With the following code the RFID Card is working well. I just have no idea on how to add the SD Card reader (i have tried using the same pins as the rfid reader and also the HSPI pins, but without success!)

Any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "web_index.h"

// Constants
const char *ssid = "****";
const char *password =  "****";
const int dns_port = 53;
const int http_port = 80;
const int ws_port = 1337;

// Globals
AsyncWebServer server(80);
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(1337);
char msg_buf[10];

// Tag reader variables
#define RFID_RC522_RST_PIN  27
#define RFID_RC522_SDA_PIN  5

MFRC522 mfrc522(RFID_RC522_SDA_PIN, RFID_RC522_RST_PIN);

bool rfid_tag_present_prev = false;
bool rfid_tag_present = false;
int _rfid_error_counter = 0;
bool _tag_found = false;

// Volume Variables
int VOLUME = 15;
int VOLUME_NORMAL_MAX = 30;
int VOLUME_LIMIT_MAX = 15;
int VOLUME_MAX = VOLUME_NORMAL_MAX;
int VOLUME_MIN = 0;
int VOLUME_CHANGE_AMOUNT = 1;
bool VOLUME_IS_LIMITED = false;

// Player variables
bool IS_PLAYING = false;
String TRACK_NAME = "-";
String ARTIST_NAME = "-";

// Button variables
const int BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PIN = 34;
bool BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_STATE = HIGH;
bool BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PREV_STATE = HIGH;

const int BUTTON_VOL_UP_PIN = 35;
bool BUTTON_VOL_UP_STATE = HIGH;
bool BUTTON_VOL_UP_PREV_STATE = HIGH;

const int BUTTON_STOP_PIN = 32;
bool BUTTON_STOP_STATE = HIGH;
bool BUTTON_STOP_PREV_STATE = HIGH;

const int BUTTON_NEXT_PIN = 33;
bool BUTTON_NEXT_STATE = HIGH;
bool BUTTON_NEXT_PREV_STATE = HIGH;

// Tag IDs
String TAG_TEST = "93 44 5C 92";
String TAG_BACH = "9C CD 69 0F";

/***********************************************************
   Functions
*/

void volumeDecrease() {
  if (VOLUME > VOLUME_MIN) {
    VOLUME = VOLUME - VOLUME_CHANGE_AMOUNT;
    broadcastUpdate();
  }
}

void volumeIncrease() {
  if (VOLUME < VOLUME_MAX) {
    VOLUME = VOLUME + VOLUME_CHANGE_AMOUNT;
    broadcastUpdate();
  } else {
    VOLUME = VOLUME_MAX;
    broadcastUpdate();
  }
}

void updateVolumeLimitState(bool state) {
  VOLUME_IS_LIMITED = state;
  broadcastUpdate();
}

void broadcastUpdate() {
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);

  doc["volume"] = VOLUME;
  doc["volume_min"] = VOLUME_MIN;
  doc["volume_max"] = VOLUME_MAX;
  doc["volume_is_limited"] = VOLUME_IS_LIMITED;
  doc["is_playing"] = IS_PLAYING;
  doc["track_name"] = TRACK_NAME;
  doc["artist_name"] = ARTIST_NAME;

  char json_string[1024];
  serializeJson(doc, json_string);
  webSocket.broadcastTXT(json_string);
}

void handleWsTextMessage(uint8_t client_num, uint8_t * payload) {
  if ( strcmp((char *)payload, "getValues") == 0 ) {
    broadcastUpdate();
  } else if ( strcmp((char *)payload, "volume_down_button_click") == 0 ) {
    volumeDecrease();
  } else if ( strcmp((char *)payload, "volume_up_button_click") == 0 ) {
    volumeIncrease();
  } else if ( strcmp((char *)payload, "volume_limit_checkbox_on") == 0 ) {
    updateVolumeLimitState(true);
  } else if ( strcmp((char *)payload, "volume_limit_checkbox_off") == 0 ) {
    updateVolumeLimitState(false);
  } else { // Message not recognized
    Serial.println("[%u] Message not recognized");
  }
}



// Callback: receiving any WebSocket message
void onWebSocketEvent(uint8_t client_num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {

  // Figure out the type of WebSocket event
  switch (type) {

    // Client has disconnected
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[%u] Disconnected!\n", client_num);
      break;

    // New client has connected
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      {
        IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(client_num);
        Serial.printf("[%u] Connection from ", client_num);
        Serial.println(ip.toString());
      }
      break;

    // Handle text messages from client
    case WStype_TEXT:

      // Print out raw message
      Serial.printf("[%u] Received text: %s\n", client_num, payload);

      handleWsTextMessage(client_num, payload);

      break;

    // For everything else: do nothing
    case WStype_BIN:
    case WStype_ERROR:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_TEXT_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_BIN_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_FIN:
    default:
      break;
  }
}

// Callback: send homepage
void onIndexRequest(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  const char* dataType = "text/html";
  IPAddress remote_ip = request->client()->remoteIP();
  Serial.println("[" + remote_ip.toString() +
                 "] HTTP GET request of " + request->url());
  //   request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", "text/html");
  AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse_P(200, dataType, index_html_gz, index_html_gz_len);
  response->addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  request->send(response);
}

// Callback: send 404 if requested file does not exist
void onPageNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  IPAddress remote_ip = request->client()->remoteIP();
  Serial.println("[" + remote_ip.toString() +
                 "] HTTP GET request of " + request->url());
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

/***********************************************************
   Main
*/

void handleButtons() {
  // VOLUME DOWN BUTTON
  bool buttonVolDownState = digitalRead(BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PIN);
  if (buttonVolDownState == LOW && BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PREV_STATE == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("button down pressed");
    volumeDecrease();
    BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PREV_STATE = LOW;
  } else if (buttonVolDownState == HIGH && BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PREV_STATE == LOW) {
    BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PREV_STATE = HIGH;
  }

  // VOLUME UP BUTTON
  bool buttonVolUpState = digitalRead(BUTTON_VOL_UP_PIN);
  if (buttonVolUpState == LOW && BUTTON_VOL_UP_PREV_STATE == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("button up pressed");
    volumeIncrease();
    BUTTON_VOL_UP_PREV_STATE = LOW;
  } else if (buttonVolUpState == HIGH && BUTTON_VOL_UP_PREV_STATE == LOW) {
    BUTTON_VOL_UP_PREV_STATE = HIGH;
  }

  // STOP BUTTON
  bool buttonStopState = digitalRead(BUTTON_STOP_PIN);
  if (buttonStopState == LOW && BUTTON_STOP_PREV_STATE == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("button stop pressed");
    volumeIncrease();
    BUTTON_STOP_PREV_STATE = LOW;
  } else if (buttonStopState == HIGH && BUTTON_STOP_PREV_STATE == LOW) {
    BUTTON_STOP_PREV_STATE = HIGH;
  }

  // NEXT BUTTON
  bool buttonNextState = digitalRead(BUTTON_NEXT_PIN);
  if (buttonNextState == LOW && BUTTON_NEXT_PREV_STATE == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("button next pressed");
    volumeIncrease();
    BUTTON_NEXT_PREV_STATE = LOW;
  } else if (buttonNextState == HIGH && BUTTON_NEXT_PREV_STATE == LOW) {
    BUTTON_NEXT_PREV_STATE = HIGH;
  }
}

String getTagUid() {
  String content = "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  content.toUpperCase();
  String tag_uid = content.substring(1);
  Serial.println("Getting tag uid");
  Serial.println(content.substring(1));
  return content.substring(1);
}

void checkTagValidity(String tag_uid) {
  if (tag_uid == TAG_TEST) {
    Serial.println("BLUE TAG");
    ARTIST_NAME = "Blue Tag";
    TRACK_NAME = "Super Track name";
    IS_PLAYING = true;
    broadcastUpdate();
  } else if (tag_uid == TAG_BACH) {
    Serial.println("BACH");
  } else {
    Serial.println("UNKNOWN CARD: ");
    Serial.print(tag_uid);
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Init buttons
  pinMode(BUTTON_VOL_DOWN_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON_VOL_UP_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON_STOP_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON_NEXT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Start Serial port
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Init SPI bus (for the tag reader)
  SPI.begin();

  // Init the tag reader
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();

  // Start access point
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

  // Print our IP address
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("AP running");
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());

  // On HTTP request for root, provide index.html file
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, onIndexRequest);

  // 404 page
  server.onNotFound(onPageNotFound);

  // Start web server
  server.begin();

  // Start WebSocket server and assign callback
  webSocket.begin();
  webSocket.onEvent(onWebSocketEvent);
}

void loop() {
  // Check for button clicks
  handleButtons();

  // Look for and handle WebSocket data
  webSocket.loop();

  rfid_tag_present_prev = rfid_tag_present;

  _rfid_error_counter += 1;
  if (_rfid_error_counter > 2) {
    _tag_found = false;
  }

  // Detect Tag without looking for collisions
  byte bufferATQA[2];
  byte bufferSize = sizeof(bufferATQA);

  // Reset baud rates
  mfrc522.PCD_WriteRegister(mfrc522.TxModeReg, 0x00);
  mfrc522.PCD_WriteRegister(mfrc522.RxModeReg, 0x00);
  // Reset ModWidthReg
  mfrc522.PCD_WriteRegister(mfrc522.ModWidthReg, 0x26);

  MFRC522::StatusCode result = mfrc522.PICC_RequestA(bufferATQA, &bufferSize);

  if (result == mfrc522.STATUS_OK) {
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { //Since a PICC placed get Serial and continue
      return;
    }
    _rfid_error_counter = 0;
    _tag_found = true;
  }

  rfid_tag_present = _tag_found;

  // rising edge
  if (rfid_tag_present && !rfid_tag_present_prev) {
    Serial.println("Tag found");
    // Get tag uid
    String tag_uid = getTagUid();

    // Check if valid tag
    checkTagValidity(tag_uid);
  }

  // falling edge
  if (!rfid_tag_present && rfid_tag_present_prev) {
    Serial.println("Tag gone");
    ARTIST_NAME = "-";
    TRACK_NAME = "-";
    IS_PLAYING = false;
    broadcastUpdate();
  }
}
```

Comment: When you tried using the same pins for the SD card reader and the RFID reader did you use different CS pins for them? Have you confirmed that your code to talk to the SD card reader works if the RFID reader isn't present?

Comment: @romkey i am not really sure if i have used 2 different pins because i am using the MFRC522 library for the RFID reader, so i am not initializing the SPI like on the examples. i am unsure which is the CS pin or how to define it (SDA is connected to D5).
I didn't didn't write any sd card relate code. I was just trying to make the RFID card reader work while using the "2 SPI buses" code (if that makes any sense)

Comment: @boguz, like romkey already mentioned: with spi a clock signal and master in slave out (miso), master out slave in (mosi) is shared between the spi slaves, a dedicated cs connection between the rfid and the master and the sd and the master signals which slave to use. SDA is for I2C protocol.

Comment: The pin you're calling `SDA_PIN` is the `CS` - Chip Select - pin. It's there in the RFID reader code. I thought you said you tried the same pins as the RFID reader... you didn't post any SD card code so I have no idea what you actually tried.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from @romkey and @RamyHx i got it to work using the same SPI pins.

My problem was that i was using the same pin for the CS of both devices. Once i change it to different CS pins for the rfid and sd card reader it started working.

For the RFID i have used the pin D2, and for the sd card reader i have used the pin D5.

For the rfid i have change `#define RFID_RC522_SDA_PIN  5` into `#define RFID_RC522_SDA_PIN  2`.

For the sd card i have used the code [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-microsd-card-arduino/), which assumes we are using the default pins (with CS connected to pin D5).